# What does "from the rough" mean?

Tags: parts-of-speech, complex-sentences

Taken from an android game "Arknights".
The whole phrase: "our colleagues in the Human Resources Department have to manage a deluge of information each and every day, but they always manage to dig out Rhodes Island's diamonds **from the rough**".

Can this **from the rough** part of the phrase be understood as "from the dirty soil"?

Comment: Usually for diamonds it's "in the rough", which means that they are uncut and unpolished. When used figuratively about people it means that they lack refinement but have valuable qualities.

Comment: There is **a mixed metaphor** there, kind of: to dig out diamonds (which are rough before they are polished). And a golfing area known as the rough, where grass grows on the edge of the fairways. When you play golf and hit the ball "into the rough", So, it's AS IF the diamonds were in the rough, and needed digging out.  Not the greatest uses of metaphor, I might add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diamonds found in jewellery ('jewelry' US) are cut, polished, shaped, etc, from 'rough diamonds' found in the ground. A finished stone is said to have been created 'from the rough'. It is not quite idiomatic to say that finished diamonds are 'dug out' from the rough, which makes me think that the sample text was prepared either by a non-native speaker, or a native speaker unfamiliar with diamond mining and gem terminology.

[Pricing diamonds from the rough](https://www.ehudlaniado.com/home/index.php/diamond-pricing/pricing-diamonds-from-the-rough)

Comment: The author is mixing his metaphors. dig out diamonds in the rough as you would "dig out" a golf ball from the rough.

Comment: There is possibly an intended pun, but it isn't worth much…

Comment: @LPH Maybe the pun is still in the oven.